# String timestamp give unrealistic date

Tags: c++

I have a ridiculous problem but I can't figure out...
I juste want to convert a timestamp string to a human readable date but the only date I have is completely wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
    char buf[80];

    std::time_t epoch = std::atol("1645128077111");
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z", std::localtime(&epoch));
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
    // Wanted value is
    // GMT: Thursday 17 February 2022 20:01:17.111
    // OR
    // Your time zone: Thursday 17 February 2022 21:01:17.111 GMT+01:00
}
```

But my output is `13-01-54102 06:25:11 CET` which is completely wrong ! I'm sure is something stupid... But I can't find it so if anybody has the answer I would be grateful.
Thanks for all :)

Comment: Why `std::time_t epoch = std::atol("1645128077111");` instead of `std::time_t epoch = 1645128077111;`?

Comment: i get `18-01-2038 19:14:07 Pacific Standard Time` on my machine

Comment: Current unix time is around 1645206000. 1645128077111 has a few extra digits. A 32 bit `long` returned by `atol` will screw this up quite nicely.

Comment: Your timestamp seems to be in milliseconds, `time_t` uses seconds https://godbolt.org/z/hh13sfMoh. @pm100 my guess would be `long` is 32-bit on your platform so `atol` fails

Comment: @AlanBirtles yup, i separated out the atol - its retunring 0x7fffffff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fwiw, in C++20:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    sys_time epoch{milliseconds{atoll("1645128077111")}};
    cout << format("{:%Z: %A %e %B %Y %T}", epoch) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
UTC: Thursday 17 February 2022 20:01:17.111
```

Not available on all platforms yet.  Encourage your vendor to catch up. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone.

```
std::time_t epoch = std::atol("1645128077111")/1000;
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z", std::localtime(&epoch));
std::cout << buf << std::endl;
```

Give me the correct answer. Dividing by 1000 convert my milliseconds to seconds.

Comment: Note: depending on the resolution of `long` on your system dividing by 1000 after `atol` may be too late.